# Where to see the data in android studio SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have an app running on my device. I am able to store and retrieve data, the question is how to view it? is there any gui available. I tried looking on the android device monitor while running my app at taskbar but under data nothing is available.
IDE: Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio

```
Tools--> Android --> Android Device Monitor
```

In  Android Device Monitor

```
Window --> Show View --> Android --> File Explorer
```

in File Explorer

```
data --> data --> Your Package Name --> databases --> sample.db
```

Pull the `db file` & you can browse your `dbms` using [sqlite browser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases)

Reference Screenshots

[image]

```
To pull the db file
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using real device then you cannot see the database in `Android Device Monitor.`

If you need to see your database then launch your application on Emulator and do the following steps:

- Launch the Android Device monitor.
- Select your package name
- Click on File `Explorer in DDMS window`.
- Go to `data -> data -> your package name -> databases`

You can export the file and view it in a sdf/sqlite browser.

Hope it helps.